# How to extend WC_Customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So Im want to modify output produced by get_downloadable_products() which can be found in WC_Customer class.

My original though was to extend WC_Customer, so I've created following folder /wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-customer.php

inside typed this:

class WC_Customer_Custom extends WC_Customer {

modified output , but cant see any changes on my website.

Can someone let me know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not extend classes. Woocommerce will ignore them. You must use add_filter() or add_action() to do stuff in wordpress.

As you can [read in function](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-customer.php#L672) it calls filter named: woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products

```
add_filter('woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'modify_downloads');
function modify_downloads($downloads) {
    // do stuff with $downloads array
    return $downloads;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I did end up extending a WC_Customer class and overridden one of functions successfully. Works fine!:D